# Show specific information using jQuery/XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I have populated a select element with XML data using jQuery, that wasn't too difficult. I'm now trying to find a way to show the information assigned to specific elements within that select element in its own, separate div area. Here's an exmaple of my code so far:

```
    $('.selectspeak').live('change', function() {

                $("#mainOutput").empty();

                $(g_playDOM).find("SPEECH").each(function(){

                    var speaker = $(".selectspeak").val();
                    var line = $(this).find("LINE").text();

                $("#mainOutput").append("<div class='speakerClass'>" + "Speaker: " + speaker + "<br />" + " <div class='speakerClassLine'>" + "<br />" + "Line: " + line + "</div>");

            });

});
```

The above code essentially populates the select tag with speaker data, no problem. But on selecting a speaker it just shows the data as normal, not the data assigned to the speaker. How can I ensure that only the assigned information will show on selecting a speaker?

I've been trying to crack this nut for a few hours now, with very little progress, so a nudge in the right direction would be fantastic! :-)

Thank you!

UPDATE: I've added a link to the live project. Just select a play on the left, then you'll be able to see the select element I'm talking about on the right hand side. Thanks.

http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00351504/COM601/assignment_2/siab.html

2nd update:

Some lines of XML as requested:

```
<PLAY>
<TITLE>The Merchant of Venice</TITLE>
<FM>
<P>
ASCII text placed in the public domain by Moby Lexical Tools, 1992.
</P>
<P>SGML markup by Jon Bosak, 1992-1994.</P>
<P>XML version by Jon Bosak, 1996-1999.</P>
<P>
The XML markup in this version is Copyright © 1999 Jon Bosak. This work may freely be distributed on condition that it not be modified or altered in any way.
</P>
</FM>
<PERSONAE>
<TITLE>Dramatis Personae</TITLE>
<PERSONA>The DUKE OF VENICE.</PERSONA>
<PGROUP>
<PERSONA>The PRINCE OF MOROCCO</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>The PRINCE OF ARRAGON</PERSONA>
<GRPDESCR>suitors to Portia.</GRPDESCR>
</PGROUP>
<PERSONA>ANTONIO, a merchant of Venice.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>BASSANIO, his friend, suitor likewise to Portia.</PERSONA>
<PGROUP>
<PERSONA>SALANIO</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>SALARINO</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>GRATIANO</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>SALERIO</PERSONA>
<GRPDESCR>friends to Antonio and Bassanio.</GRPDESCR>
</PGROUP>
<PERSONA>LORENZO, in love with Jessica.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>SHYLOCK, a rich Jew.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>TUBAL, a Jew, his friend.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>LAUNCELOT GOBBO, the clown, servant to SHYLOCK.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>OLD GOBBO, father to Launcelot.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>LEONARDO, servant to BASSANIO.</PERSONA>
<PGROUP>
<PERSONA>BALTHASAR</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>STEPHANO</PERSONA>
<GRPDESCR>servants to PORTIA.</GRPDESCR>
</PGROUP>
<PERSONA>PORTIA, a rich heiress.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>NERISSA, her waiting-maid.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>JESSICA, daughter to SHYLOCK.</PERSONA>
<PERSONA>
Magnificoes of Venice, Officers of the Court of Justice, Gaoler, Servants to Portia, and other Attendants.
</PERSONA>
</PERSONAE>
<SCNDESCR>
SCENE Partly at Venice, and partly at Belmont, the seat of PORTIA, on the Continent.
</SCNDESCR>
<PLAYSUBT>THE MERCHANT OF VENICE</PLAYSUBT>
<ACT>
<TITLE>ACT I</TITLE>
<SCENE>
<TITLE>SCENE I. Venice. A street.</TITLE>
<STAGEDIR>Enter ANTONIO, SALARINO, and SALANIO</STAGEDIR>
<SPEECH>
<SPEAKER>ANTONIO</SPEAKER>
<LINE>In sooth, I know not why I am so sad:</LINE>
<LINE>It wearies me; you say it wearies you;</LINE>
<LINE>But how I caught it, found it, or came by it,</LINE>
<LINE>What stuff 'tis made of, whereof it is born,</LINE>
<LINE>I am to learn;</LINE>
<LINE>And such a want-wit sadness makes of me,</LINE>
<LINE>That I have much ado to know myself.</LINE>
</SPEECH>
```

Comment: Making an example on jsfiddle.net would help a lot here.

Comment: We like to see several lines of the XML too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to filter the selected "SPEECH" items.

```
$('.selectspeak').live('change', function() {

                $("#mainOutput").empty();

                $(g_playDOM).find("SPEECH").each(function(){

                    var speaker = $(".selectspeak").val();
                    //I'm checking if this 'SPEECH' is by "SPEAKER"
                    if($(this).find("SPEAKER").text()==speaker){


                    var line = $(this).find("LINE").text();
                    $("#mainOutput").append("<div class='speakerClass'>" + "Speaker: " + speaker + "<br />" + " <div class='speakerClassLine'>" + "<br />" + "Line: " + line + "</div>");
                    }



            });

});​
```

Here I checked if the selected "SPEECH" item is of the "Speaker".

Comment: However it is good if you can use something like XPath. It took a long time to load that big XML! I thought it is not working! [link]http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks so much agentmilindu, that seems to have done the job - and it seems to be such an elegant solution. Thank you also for the XPath suggestion, I agree with this. The XML was set out by my lecturer and it does at times take far too long to load. Thank you again.